# MDBootstrap Steppers

Tags: javascript, css, mdbootstrap

I am using **MDBootstrap Steppers**, the documentation has only the **css** to achieve the layout. Now I want to implement the previous and next button functionalities. Anyone here to guide me.

Answer (score 1):

Recently, we've expanded our stepper component so you can now use prev/next buttons. [Here](https://mdbootstrap.com/components/bootstrap-steps-stepper) you can find more information about the implementation